# Не получается делать математические решения

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Делаю бота для рп. Нужно чтобы отнимались числа.

```
@client.command()
async def тест_создать(ctx):
    def check(m: discord.Message):  # m = discord.Message.
        return m.author.id == ctx.author.id and m.channel.id == ctx.channel.id 
    await ctx.send('Введите кол-во дерева')
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    cost = str(3)
    answer =  str(msg.content)
    if answer < cost:
        await ctx.send('Недостаточно ресов')
    if answer >= cost:
        await ctx.send('Вы скрафтили челов')
        await ctx.send({answer}-{cost} + ' дерева осталось')
```

В итоге ошибка выглядит так:

```
Ignoring exception in command тест_создать:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\zombibox\Desktop\Питон проэкты\попыт рп\politrp.py", line 75, in тест_создать
    await ctx.send({answer}-{cost} + ' дерева осталось')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'str'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'str'
```

Comment: Ну так переведите в числа (int) и отнимите.

Answer (score 0):

Из ошибки ясно, что нельзя складывать `set` и `str`

```
@client.command()
async def тест_создать(ctx):
    def check(m: discord.Message):  # m = discord.Message.
        return m.author.id == ctx.author.id and m.channel.id == ctx.channel.id 
    await ctx.send('Введите кол-во дерева')
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    cost = str(3)
    answer =  str(msg.content)
    if answer < cost:
        await ctx.send('Недостаточно ресов')
    if answer >= cost:
        await ctx.send('Вы скрафтили челов')
        await ctx.send({int(answer)}-{int(cost)} + ' дерева осталось')
```

Comment: Там наверное `f-стринг` должна быть вообще, иначе к чему фигурные скобки

Comment: Однако вы всё-равно складываете.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное так нужно:

```
cost = 3
answer = int(msg.content))
if answer < cost:
    await ctx.send('Недостаточно ресов')
if answer >= cost:
    await ctx.send('Вы скрафтили челов')
    await ctx.send(f'{answer-cost} дерева осталось')
```

То есть:

- сравниваем числа, а не строки
- генерируем выходную строку с помощью `f-string`

А у вас фигурные скобки использовались без `f-string`, из-за чего воспринимались, как оборачивание переменной в множество.